# Tring to load csv file in Pandas using dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load a csv file within a data frame based in pandas. I have used the following imports.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

It is throwing error that file is not found the traceback is as follows:

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('purchases.csv')
>
> c:\users\saish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names,
>   index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine,
>   converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows,
>   nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose,
>   skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col,
>   date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands,
>   decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment,
>   encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines,
>   skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray,
>   compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map,
>   float_precision)
>       703                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
>       704 
>   --> 705         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       706 
>       707     parser_f.**name** = name
>
> c:\users\saish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>       443 
>       444     # Create the parser.
>   --> 445     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
>       446 
>       447     if chunksize or iterator:
>
> c:\users\saish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in **init**(self, f, engine, **kwds)
>       812             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
>       813 
>   --> 814         self._make_engine(self.engine)
>       815 
>       816     def close(self):
>
> c:\users\saish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in _make_engine(self, engine)    1043     def _make_engine(self,
>   engine='c'):    1044         if engine == 'c':
>   -> 1045             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)    1046         else:    1047             if engine == 'python':
>
> c:\users\saish\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py
>   in **init**(self, src, **kwds)    1682
>   kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False    1683 
>   -> 1684         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)    1685     1686         # XXX
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.**cinit**()
>
> pandas_libs\parsers.pyx in
>   pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()
>
> FileNotFoundError: File b'purchases.csv' does not exist

Comment: Are you super sure the file exists? Try df = pd.read_csv(r'purchases.csv') if you are.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @SuperStew I have tried that it is throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used command `pwd` to get the working directory and then placed the csv file along with the .ipynb file in the same directory.